# How to find required fields for an sObject?

Tags: apex, insert, required-field, required

I know the question has already been posted, and answers where given ;
I read [this topic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/59817/find-required-values-for-salesforce-objects) ;
Of course I can try to insert the sObject and get the error listing the missing fields,

But isn't it a 'better' way to do it ?

I'm pretty sure I had found a way, but can't find it anymore ;

At this moment my favorite option remains to use the Schema Builder in wich it's obvious (red lines in front of each required attribute) -->

[image]

But isn't it a way to show a column required / not required, in the object manager ? -->

[image]

Same question, in the dev console ? -->

[image]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Looks like a candidate for idea exchange.

Comment: How do you do ? How do people do, most of the time ? Thanks !

Comment: I use IDE like eclipse/VS code to retreive metadata of Object. The metadata XML contains a required tag which tells me if its a required field of not. Other way is looking at UI/Describe call like you mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note that fields can be made required via other means which are difficult or impossible to detect. Validation rules, triggers, and Process Builder can all introduce errors when a field is not populated (sometimes more intentionally than others).

Given the above, you can still iterate the describe to find which fields are practically required if you like. Here is a script showing how to do so.

```
for (SObjectField field : SObjectType.MyObject__c.fields.getMap().values())
{
    if (!field.getDescribe().isNillable())
    {
        system.debug(field);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this pointing this issue, and thanks for the code ! Ok, I'll assume my idea wasn't as good as it first seem to me, thanks for your usefull help !

Answer (score 2):

For API version <= 44.0, there is no explicit isRequired method but there are a few methods that you can leverage to find required fields:

```
for (Schema.SObjectField fieldToken : Schema.SObjectType.MyObject__c.fields.getMap().values())
{
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = fieldToken.getDescribe();
    if (
        // These methods are on DescribeFieldResult
        !fieldDescribe.isNillable()
        && fieldDescribe.isCustom()
        && !fieldDescribe.isDefaultedOnCreate() // optional
    )
    {
        system.debug(field);
    }
}
```

[Schema.DescribeFieldResult Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm)

`!isNillable()` won't exactly get you your required fields since this will also catch auto-numbers and system fields (like `Deleted`).

`isCustom()` I believe is an auto-inclusion since this type of use case typically relates to custom objects and using auto-numbering for a `Name` is pretty common in my experience. Exclude this is you are leveraging the standard required fields for record creation.

`!isDefaultedOnCreate()` may be good to add depending on whether or not you care about values being explicitly declared that would otherwise default.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I'm not providing any answers to the original question, I want to add more information to this post that could be useful for others.

Apparently, the `nillable` field in the [**SObject Describe**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm) API is not related to the required/optional property of an SObject fields.

Take for instance the [description of the `ServiceAppointment` object](https://gist.github.com/jverce/62e8aed7b56aab8e3a3bcd6eaba7f612), which specifies the `ParentRecordId` as nillable. However, the following code fails:

```
ServiceAppointment sa = new ServiceAppointment();
insert sa;
```

The error code I receive when trying to execute the code above is:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: 
REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [ParentRecordId]: [ParentRecordId]
```

So if we take that error message as truthful, we can succeed:

```
Account a = new Account(Name='Some Name');  // `Name` is required for `Account`.
insert a;
ServiceAppointment sa = new ServiceAppointment(ParentRecordId=a.Id);
insert sa;
```

In fact, none of the fields marked as non-nillable are actually required when creating a `ServiceAppointment` object. Such fields are the following:

```js
[
  "Id",
  "OwnerId",
  "IsDeleted",
  "AppointmentNumber",
  "CreatedDate",
  "CreatedById",
  "LastModifiedDate",
  "LastModifiedById",
  "SystemModstamp",
  "Address",
  "EarliestStartTime",
  "DueDate",
  "IsAnonymousBooking"
]
```

The reason behind that I think is that all of them are provided with default values when creating a record even though they are not flagged as `defaultValue`, `defaultValueFormula` nor `defaultedOnCreate` (which makes it even more confusing ).

I did find out however that the following formula closely approximates the required fields shown in the GUI

```js
function isFieldMandatory(field) {
  return (
    field.createable &&
    !field.defaultedOnCreate &&
    !field.nillable
  );
}
```

Such formula will say that the following fields are mandatory, which "matches" what is shown in the GUI (with the exception of the only actual required field, whcih is `ParentRecordId`):

```js
[
  "EarliestStartTime",
  "DueDate"
]
```

[image: New Service Appointment GUI form]

So a message to you, future hackers:
I wish you better luck that what I had so far

Answer (score 0):

Found this,
Could help also !

Not responding at my whole question, but helps.

[image]